# Kind of Diophantine Equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, equivalence-relations

I was trying to approach an equation of the type:

$$
\alpha m + \beta = n^2
$$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are given integer constants and $m$ and $n$ are integer to be found. Is there a standard way to approach equations like these? If so, can you share me a link or some useful material?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Here this http://swc.math.arizona.edu/aws/2006/06CohenLectures.pdf if you're interested, although it might be a bit too comprehensive depending on what you're looking for.

Comment: The first thing that jumps out at me is that $\alpha m+\beta$ has to be a square, which implies that $\alpha m+\beta$ is a multiple of $4$ or $1$ greater than a multiple of $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation of

$$\alpha m + \beta = n^2 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

means that if $\alpha = 0$, there's a solution only if $\beta$ is a perfect square, with $n$ then being $\sqrt{\beta}$ and $m$ being any integer.

For $\alpha \neq 0$, one other restriction to consider is if there's any prime $p$ where the # of factors of it in $\beta$, call it $q$, is odd and the number of factors of $p$ in $\alpha$ is $\gt q$. In those cases, there are no solutions since $\alpha m + \beta$ would have the odd $r$ factors of $p$, but $n^2$ must have an even number of factors of $p$.

Apart from the restrictions mentioned above, note you have

$$\beta \equiv n^2 \pmod{\alpha} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

i.e., $\beta$ must be a [quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) modulo $\alpha$. Any $n$ which satisfies \eqref{eq2A} will then have a corresponding $m$ from \eqref{eq1A} of $m = \frac{n^2 - \beta}{\alpha}$. As for finding an $n$, as suggested by [Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8508/robert-israel)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3770312/kind-of-diophantine-equation/3770331?noredirect=1#comment7759286_3770331), the [Complexity of finding square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Complexity_of_finding_square_roots) Wikipedia article section describes several algorithmic methods.

However, note if $\beta$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $\alpha$, then there are no solutions. For example, if $\alpha$ is a multiple of $3$ and $\beta \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, there are no solutions since $2$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $3$, i.e., there's no $n$ such that $n^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$.

Comment: For methods of finding $n$, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Complexity_of_finding_square_roots)

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for your suggestion. I added the Wikipedia article section link to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$\alpha m + \beta = n^2$

Given $(\alpha,\beta)$ as,

$(\alpha,\beta)$=$[w^2,4w^2(k^2-1)]$ then,

w=(2k-3)

$n=(6k^2-13k+6)$

$m=(5k^2-12k+8)$

For, $k=3$, we get:

$(\alpha,\beta)$=$(9,288)$ and

(n,m)=(21,17)